# dynamically create PHP navigation menu from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, navigation

I have seen so many examples but wasn't able to find an exact answer. Most of the question answered either have errors of are not answered properly. If anyone knows of a finished solution similar to my question, please point me in that direction!

```
   $menu = Array
(
    [dashboard] => Array
        (
            [main] => /phone/summary
            [main_selected] => 1
            [child_selected] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [phones] => /phones
                    [tablets] => /tablets
                )

        )

    [mobile templates] => Array
        (
            [main] => /phone/templates
            [main_selected] => 
        )

    [phone size] => Array
        (
            [main] => link_3
            [main_selected] => 
            [child_selected] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [iphone] => /phone/iphone_size
                    [samsung] => /phone/samsung_size
                    [android] => /phone/android_size
                    [blackberry] => /phone/blackberry_size
                    [google_pixels] => /phone/google_phone_size
                )

        )

    [phone chart] => Array
        (
            [main] => /phone/charts/
            [main_selected] => 
        )


)
```

And here is what I would like to turn it into:

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Dashboard<a/>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/phones">Iphone</a></li>
            <li><a href="/tablets">Tablets</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/phone/templates">mobile templates<a/>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link_3">phone size<a/>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/phone/iphone_size">Iphone</a></li>
            <li><a href="/phone/samsung_size">Samsung</a></li>
            <li><a href="/phone/android_size">Android</a></li>
            <li><a href="/phone/blackberry_size">Blackberry</a></li>
            <li><a href="/phone/google_phone_size">Google_pixels</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/phone/charts/">phone chart<a/></li>
</ul>
```

Hope someone understands what is displayed.
This is what I have tried. Sure it's not very great.

```
public function sideMenu($actions, $level = 0)
    {
        $xhtml = '';
        $main_menu = null;
        $ret = "";
        $test = "";

        foreach ($actions as $key => $value) 
        {    
            if(isset($value['children']))
            {
                $main_menu .= "<li>".$key."<li>";
                //print_r($main_menu);

                if (is_array($value["children"])) 
                {
                    $ret .= "<ul>";
                    $test = $value["children"];
                    foreach ($test as $k1 => $v1) 
                    {

                        $ret .= "<li> ".$k1." </li>";


                    }
                    $ret .= "</ul>";
                    print_r($ret);
                }


            }
            else
            {
                $main_menu .= "<li>".$key."</li>";
            }   

        }


        return $xhtml;
    }
```

Comment: Share what you have tried till yet?

Comment: It will need a lot of codes to parse your array and generate the HTML. You can try writing the codes.

Comment: this is a lot of work kind of. You need to try something, then we can help

Comment: Don't actually know where to start as am new to PHP

Comment: You could start with a valid Array. Then you are creating $main_menu but don't seem to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function sideMenu($actions){
    $main_menu = "<ul>";
    foreach ($actions as $key => $value) 
    {    
        $main_menu .= "<li><a href='".$value['main']."'>".$key."</a>";
        if(isset($value['children']) && is_array($value['children'])){
            $main_menu .= "<ul>";
            foreach($value['children'] as $k => $v){
                $main_menu .= "<li><a href='".$v."'>".$k."</a></li>";
            }
            $main_menu .= "</ul>";
        }
        $main_menu .= "</li>";
    }

    $main_menu .= "</ul>";
    return $main_menu;
}
```

I have updated your sideMenu function and you can call it by 
`echo $obj->sideMenu($menu);` Where `$obj` is your class object where this function is defined.

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/795250)

Comment: Just thinking. Is there a different way to building up the code to bring the same result.

Comment: It is understandable customized and optimized solution for a two-level menu of your array. If you have the same structure for parent and child menu item we can call the same function recursively for n level.

Comment: Would you just add an extra foreach, if you are dealing with a three-level menu

Comment: If array structure remains as same as parent array, we do not need extra foreach. If array structure is as same as like current array, we must add extra foreach.

Comment: Because, Current array contains 'Menu Value'=>array( 'main' => URL); and childern contains 'Menu Value'=>URL;