# Show All Data list of multidimensional array Using Foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is The My Array Code...

```
$data = array(
            'data_1',
            'data_2',
            'data_3',
            'data_4',
            'data_5' => array(
                            'data_5_1',
                            'data_5_2'
                        )
);
```

i Want to Ountput Like The : -

```
data_1
data_2
data_3
data_4
data_5
    data_5_1
    data_5_2
```

Here is My Code I try to Self But I Show Error

```
foreach($data as $da){ 
     echo $da."<br>";
}
```

Error Found Like This

```
data_1
data_2
data_3
data_4
Notice: Array to string conversion in filename.php on line 3
Array
```

Please Fix this problem & Use echo not print_r

Comment: Function `is_array`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best achieved with a recursive function so that you can deal with any level of nested arrays:

```
function display_list($array) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            echo "$k\n";
            display_list($v);
        }
        else {
            echo "$v\n";
        }
    }
}
display_list($data);
```

Output:

```
data_1
data_2
data_3 
data_4 
data_5 
data_5_1 
data_5_2
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ut9t8)

Comment: if I want Drop Down of The list Like i Select data_5 then show  data_5_1 
data_5_2

Comment: @sanjayjoon I suggest you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747156/php-create-navigation-menu-from-multidimensional-array-dynamically or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976836/dynamically-create-php-navigation-menu-from-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1):

You could use iterators:

```
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data)) as $item)
  echo "$item<br>", PHP_EOL;
```

As asked in comments, if you want either the key or value depending on type, you can use the flag `SELF_FIRST` and the ternary operator:

```
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $key => $item)
  echo (is_scalar($item) ? $item : $key) . '<br>', PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but it doesn't print out the `data_5` *key* value...

Comment: @Nick I've added a version also showing keys when the item is an array.

Comment: Looks good now, although it lost some of the nice cleanness that the first version had. pity...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as $val) {
    if(is_array($val)){
        foreach ($val as $row) {
            echo "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row;
        }
    }
    else{ 
         echo "<br>".$val;
    }
}
```

Comment: data_5 Not Found in Output